# Date type required in AEM HTL / Sightly date formatter

Tags: date, format, aem, sightly, htl

I've seen that since AEM 6.3, date formatting has been natively supported in the markup, like so:

```
${ 'dd~MMMM-yyyy' @ format=currentPage.jcr:created }
```

(Reference: https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#1222-dates )

I have tried playing with this formatter using that jcr:created property, as well as data coming from the backend in `java.util.Date`.

My question is, are *other* date types supported? Like say, `java.time.LocalDate`? It doesn't display on my test pages, although I'm not sure if I'm just missing some additional property that needs to be indicated on the HTL markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the documentation as far as I can tell but Apache Sling is an open source project so we can look it up on our own.

Looking at the implementation details, the only supported types as of now are `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` and their sub-classes.

Here's the [`FormatFilterExtension` class](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/engine/extension/FormatFilterExtension.java) responsible for applying the chosen format in HTL.

Let's have a look at the check it performs.

```
 } else if (DATE_FORMAT_TYPE.equals(formattingType) || (!hasPlaceHolders && runtimeObjectModel.isDate(formatObject))) {
      Locale locale = getLocale(runtimeObjectModel, options);
      TimeZone timezone = getTimezone(runtimeObjectModel, options);
      return formatDate(source, runtimeObjectModel.toDate(formatObject), locale, timezone);
 }
```

It uses `runtimeObjectModel.isDate()` to verify if we're dealing with a date. If we look at `runtimeObjectModel`, we can see that it's an instance of [`SlingRuntimeObjectModel`](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/engine/runtime/SlingRuntimeObjectModel.java) which in turn extends [`AbstractRuntimeModel`](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly-runtime/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/render/AbstractRuntimeObjectModel.java).

```
@Override
public boolean isDate(Object target) {
    return (target instanceof Date || target instanceof Calendar);
}
```

so if it's a `Date` or a `Calendar`, it will be handled.

Even if you force the formatting type like this

```
${'yyyy-MM-dd' @ format=myDate, type='date'} <!--/* Forced formatting type */-->
```

the object you pass will end up being processed using [`AbstractRuntimeObjectModel#toDate(Object object)`](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly-runtime/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/render/AbstractRuntimeObjectModel.java#L90) which returns `null` for all objects that aren't instances of `Date` or `Calendar`.

Since the check is based on `instanceof`, this also includes instances of `Date` and `Calendar`'s sub-types. [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), however, is not one of them so it's not surprising that it didn't work.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help in pointing that out!

However, does this mean we can suggest to Adobe to consider this a bug or improvement? Unless the feature that allows for date formatting is very specifically designed for dates stored in JCR only (which are not of type LocalDate)?

Comment: @ionmarx HTL is part of Apache Sling so if you have an idea for an improvement, you can raise a ticket in the Sling Jira.

Comment: It it ends up being implemented in Sling, you'll have to upgrade the HTL bundles on AEM. This is something you'd want to consult with Adobe.

Comment: @ionmarx: toniedzwiedz is right, you can propose an improvement in Sling and also open an issue with Adobe for it to be included in AEM (via SP)

Comment: Alright! Thank you for the tips! Will also look at raising a ticket, if it makes sense to them! :D